# ASP.NET 3.1 MVC: Displaying UserIdentity details in View() when clicking their names on the website

Tags: asp.net-mvc

So I've made a forum-like website using asp.net mvc. I really don't know how to approach this problem. I want to redirect users to a User Details View Page that would display their Username, Email, Etc, whenever they click the OP's username on their posts. Can anyone help?

Here is what I've already made. Thank you :)

Please tell me if I need to upload a specific code from my controller or model so it would be clearer... Thanks again :D

[image]

Comment: More context to this problem would be needed, will need to see how your controller and view model works

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create an action method within your controller that returns a model with the relevant user details.

Example:

Say I have a `AppUser` class that extends `IdentityUser` with a `Subscription` property:

```
public class AppUser : IdentityUser
  {
      [Required]
      public string Subscription { get; set; }
  }
```

I have a controller with a `MyAccount()` action method that returns a View with the user model:

```
[Authorize]
public async Task<IActionResult> MyAccount()
{
   AppUser user = await userManager.FindByNameAsync(User.Identity.Name);
   if (user != null)
   {
       return View(user);
   }
   else
   {
       return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
   }
}
```

If you want to use any user (instead of the `AppUser` logged into the client machine), you can bind the ID to the model that calls an `AnyAccount` action method and then return the user based on that information. For example

```
    [Authorize]
    public async Task<IActionResult> AnyAccount(int userID)
    {
       AppUser user = await userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);
       if (user != null)
       {
           return View(user);
       }//...
    }
```

I then create a View to display those user details I want to show:

```
<div class="buffer cos-xs-12">
    <div class="bg-primary panel-body text-center"><h4>@ViewBag.Title</h4></div>

    <table class="table table-condensed table-bordered">
        <tr><td><strong>Name</strong></td><td>@Model.UserName</td></tr>
        <tr><td><strong>Email</strong></td><td>@Model.Email</td></tr>
        <tr><td><strong>Subscription</strong></td><td>@Model.Subscription</td></tr>
    </table>
</div>
```